# Absolute positioning and its parent element

Tags: css, position, css-position

I've always heard that when you use absolute positioning that the element you want to act as its parent needs to have a `position` of `relative`.

I was trying to build a CSS dropdown menu and I was struggling to get the dropdown menu items stretch beyond the width of the main menu item when I had its parent element I wanted it to use set as `relative`; the text in the drop down menu items would just wrap.

So I looked around at other example menus to see how they did it and one I found wasn't even using any parent elements with a `position` of `relative` even though they were using absolute positioning like I was.

That example is here: http://purecssmenu.com/

So I tried removing my `relative` positioning and bingo - my problem went away. However now I am using absolute positioning with none of it's parents using `relative` positioning, they are all set to `static`.

So I'm wondering how that makes sense - with no `relative` parents wouldn't it fall back to the browser window?

If need be, here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="navWrapper">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="about"><a href="about_us/">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="trademark"><a href="freetrademarksearch/">Free Trademark Search</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="services">
                    <a href="services/">Services</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="">Trademark Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Prepare &amp; File Trademark</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Trademark Infringement</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="testimonials"><a href="testimonials/">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="more"><a href="javascript:void(0);">More Information</a></li>
                <li class="spacer"></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>                 
            </ul>
            <div class="contentClear"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Nav Ends -->
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav Wrapper Ends -->
```

CSS:

```
#header .navWrapper {
    width: 1004px;
}

#header .navWrapper .left {
    float: left;
    width: 4px;
    min-width: 4px;
    height: 47px;
    min-height: 47px;
    background: url('../images/nav-left-bg.png') left top no-repeat;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav {
    float: left;
    width: 994px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0d0b4;
    border-left: 1px solid #e0d0b4;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0d0b4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8dcc8;
    background: url('../images/nav-button-bg.png') left top repeat-x;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav ul {
    margin: 0 1px;
    display: block;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    font-family: OpenSansBold, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 2.9;
    text-align: center;
    color: #646464;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li.spacer {
    width: 2px;
    min-width: 2px;
    height: 45px;
    min-height: 45px;
    background: url('../images/nav-button-spacer-bg.png') left top no-repeat;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li a,
#header .navWrapper .nav li a:visited
{
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #646464;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li a:hover,
#header .navWrapper .nav li a:active,
#header .navWrapper .nav li a:focus
{
    color: #fff;
    background: url('../images/nav-button-bg.png') left bottom repeat-x;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li.home {
    max-width: 86px;
    text-indent: -1px;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: OpenSansSemibold, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2.3;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4771d;
    color: #fff;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a,
#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a
{
    color: #fff;
    height: auto;
}

#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a:hover,
#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a:focus,
#header .navWrapper .nav li ul.sub li a:active
{
    background: #d66627;
}

#header .navWrapper .right {
    float: right;
    width: 4px;
    min-width: 4px;
    height: 47px;
    min-height: 47px;    
    background: url('../images/nav-right-bg.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please see my latest update, which shows how you can see how http://purecssmenu.com/ *is* applying `position:relative` to the parent `<ul>` on `:hover`

Comment: Ok I see it, but I think you mean the parent `<li>`, not `<ul>`. :)

Comment: I see. This is working for you because, although you have set `position:absolute` on the list, you have not defined any of the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, or `right` properties. Those properties **do not** just default to 0. When neither `top` nor `bottom` is specified, the element is vertically positioned where it would otherwise be positioned were it still part of the flow. Same goes for `left` and `right` and horizontal positioning. Try setting any one of those properties to 0px, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: ...so in your case, setting `position:absolute` is needed becaues it removes the sub-menu from the flow, allowing the container li, which doesn't have a specified width, to keep the width computed by the text at the top of the menu. Whereas if you had `position:relative`, on the sub-list,  its width would force the containing li to widen, causing the "Contact Us item to drop to the next line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It falls back to the nearest *ancestor* element that has position defined as `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed` -- not just `relative`, but any value other than `static` (the default).

Generally, you'd want to position the item absolutely according to a grid established by its parent. However, sometimes it makes sense to have it positioned to a grid established by a higher up element.

For example:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2-A">[some content]</div>
        <div id="div2-B">
            <div id="div3">[more content]</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1{
    width:1024px;margin:auto;
    position:relative
}
#div3{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px; left:0px;
}
```

In this case, div3 will be positioned all the way to the left & bottom of div1 -- its grandfather -- because its immediate parent (div2) has the default `position:static`, and so does not establish as an absolute positioning context/grid for its children. But div3 will *not* (necessarily) go all the way to the left of the viewport or the page body because the next higher up element (div1) has position defined as relative.

**UPDATE**
In the case you provided (http://purecssmenu.com/), the position:relative declaration is being applied on the :hover pseudo-class, so you won't see it immediately in the styles listed for Google Developer Tools or Firebug.

You can inspect this in Google developer tools by inspecting the parent element, then in the right-hand side of the "Styles" panel, click the "Toggle Element State" button, (looks like a box with dotted border and an arrow pointing in it), then check the box next to ":hover".  I'm sure Firebug has something similar.

You'll see this declaration added to the list:

```
ul.cssMenu li:hover { position: relative; }
```

This works because when you're not hovering on the parent `<li>`, the sub-menu `<ul>` is hidden with `display:none`, so it doesn't matter where it's positioned.

Comment: Thanks, but even on that page you can see all the parent elements of the absolute positioned nested `UL` have `static` positioning.

Comment: You missed the declaration on its parents hover `ul.cssMenu li:hover {
position: relative; }`

Comment: good answer! but why not just set position:relative to the li from the beginning? Why just on hover?

Comment: @Niklas: Actually, there's no reason for that (or maybe it's just to confuse us!). I'm just reporting how the folks at http://purecssmenu.com/ did it.

Comment: @Faust haha, then they succeeded on me ;-)

Comment: I have NO `relative` setting in my CSS as you can see above yet my menu displays fine. If I add `relative` to the parent `<li>` as that site does it wraps the text, if I add it only on `hover` then it wraps the text on hover. It's weird. Guess I'll have to upload it so you can see.

Comment: Ok, FWIW I fixed the wrapping issue by using `white-space: nowrap`; however I still didn't need to use `relative` at all, which you can see here: http://www.condorstudios.com/stuff/temp/

Comment: @Brett: just added comments under your question, but meant to put them here.

Answer (score 2):

Another note on the ***nearest ancestor*** when an element is being positioned.

Three years later after the OP, CSS3 properties like transform are more widely being used, which implicitly creates a new containing block, forcing the element to have `position: relative/absolute;`

So to make sure *intermediary* parent elements have no effect in the positioning of a child element, you need check it has `position: static` and no `transforms` set.

Example

```
    <div id="one">
      <div id="two">
        <div id="three"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
    #one {
      position: relative;
    }
    #two {
      position: static;
      transform: none;
    }
    #three {
      position:absolute;
    }
```