# How to use absolute position relative to parent element

Tags: html, css, razor

html report contains rows whose elements should printed in same line.
Only absolute left positions are specified at design time.

Each row should appear in next line after previous row without explicit top attribute like

```
   row1 field1                          row1 field2
              row2 field1    row2 field2
```

According to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm and [Absolute positioning and its parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862330/absolute-positioning-and-its-parent-element) 
absolute position is from parent relative element position.

So this must work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .row {
            position: relative;
        }

        .field {
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class='row'>
<div class='field' style='left:5cm'>row1 field1</div>
<div class='field' style='left:16cm'>row1 field2</div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
<div class='field' style='left:8cm'>row2 field1</div>
<div class='field' style='left:12cm'>row2 field2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, it does not work for unknown reason. All elements appear in same row:

```
row1 field1  row2 field1  row2 field2  row1 field2
```

Adding top attributes from **top of screen** produces desired layout:

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='field' style='top:1cm;left:5cm'>row1 field1</div>
<div class='field' style='top:1cm;left:16cm'>row1 field2</div>
</div>

<div class='row'>
<div class='field' style='top:2cm;left:8cm'>row2 field1</div>
<div class='field' style='top:2cm;left:12cm'>row2 field2</div>
</div>
```

Elements heights and browser rendered line heights may vary. Big empty space between rows should
eliminated.  So it is difficult to calculate poper top  values as this html requires.

How to get desired layout  without using top attribute?
Every row div element should start in next row after previous row element like browser normally
renders block elements.

I can use table or other widely implemented elements if this helps instead of divs. This report is Razor view generated at runtime from ASP.NET MVC4 application and run using RazorEngine go get html which is rendered in desktop modern browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving each `.row` a `height` attribute

```
.row {
    position: relative;
    height:1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gTp2t/

divs typically have a zero or null height effect when they are not explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using absolute you can simply use float:left on fields to get the desired effect. You won't need to set top and left too instead width only if required.