# Dynamic generation of images with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

As part of a Coursera exercise, I am trying to show the same photo at 5 different positions of a `<div>`.  Although I used `absolute` positioning, all photos seem to be stacked above each other.

here is the code I am trying to use in the body tag:

```
      <div id="leftside"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftside");
      function generateFaces(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          photo = document.createElement("img");
          photo.src ="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
              topPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*401);
              leftPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*401);
              photo.style.top =topPosition;
              photo.style.left =leftPosition;
              theLeftSide.appendChild(photo);
              console.log(i, topPosition, leftPosition);
            } // for
          } // function
          window.onload = generateFaces();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out units in the positions. If you only provide number it is ignored

Try changing to :

```
var  topPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*401) +'px';
var  leftPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*401) +'px';
                                                 // ^^ units needed
```

```js
var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftside");

function generateFaces() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var photo = document.createElement("img");
    photo.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
    var topPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + 'px';
    var leftPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 401) + 'px';
    //console.log()
    photo.style.top = topPosition;
    photo.style.left = leftPosition;
    theLeftSide.appendChild(photo);
    console.log(i, topPosition, leftPosition);
  } // for
} // function
window.onload = generateFaces;
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div id="leftside"></div>
```

---

Also note that `window.onload = generateFaces();` is incorrect. You want to pass function as reference, not invoke it .... `window.onload = generateFaces;`

Answer (score 0):

The parent element (or some *ancestor*) must have at least `position: relative` for its children `position` to work.

In this answer is fully explained: [Absolute positioning and its parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862330/absolute-positioning-and-its-parent-element)

Put this style to your object:

```
<div id="leftside" style='position: relative;'></div>
```

Comment: true but if no ancestor has position they will be placed absolute in document...not stacked